# Получить данные из jsona

Tags: php

Почему не выводится результат метода getTitle()?

```
class News{
    private $title;
    private $date;
    private $author;
    private $description;

    public function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }
    public function setTitle($title){
        $this->$title = $title;
        return $this;
    }

    public static function createFromJsonFile($filename) {
        $json = file_get_contents($filename);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        $news = new News();
        $news->setTitle($data['news']['title']);
        return $news;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Новости сайта</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Последние новости</h2>
        <?php
            $news1 = News::createFromJsonFile('news1.json');
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($news1->getTitle());
            echo '</pre>';

        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**json**

```
{
    "news": {
        "title": "Современная медицина",
        "date": "05.04.2017",
        "author": "Admin",
        "description": "Русским учённым придуман специальный луч, который может удалить аппендицит, без вскрытия"
    }
}
```

Comment: а что выводится? наверняка ошибка какая-то, которую вы прочитали и она наверняка связана не с json, а со считыванием файла

Answer (score 1):

```
public function setTitle($title){
    $this->title = $title;
    return $this;
}
```